# How to drag and rotate orthographic map (globe) using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, drag

**The SetUp:**  I'm building a globe app to better visually represent data of regions of the world.  It is built d3.js using topojson to build the geometry.

I'm currently implementing a drag as was achieved by ivyywang [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ivyywang/7c94cb5a3accd9913263).
(don't get lost in the math functions unless you are status: "math nerd guru" )

My project is currently [here](http://danefrost.com/projects/globeApp/globeApp.php).

**The Problem:**  I got the globe projected orthographically, and have implemented the drag function with success... except.  I can only click and drag the globe as long as my cursor is inside of the bounds of a country.  How can I project my SVG so that the whole canvas responds to my drag event?

**Relevant Code:**

first I get some data from a MySQL request and store it in countryStattistics.  And I run it through the following function to better index it.

```
var countryStatistics = (returned from mySQL query)

  //this function build dataById[] setting data keyed to idTopo
function keyIdToData(d){
  countryStatistics.forEach(function(d) {
    dataById[d.idTopo] = d;
  });  
}    

 function visualize(statisticalData, mapType){
  //pass arguments each function call to decide what data to viasually display, and what map type to use

var margin = {top: 100, left: 100, right: 100, bottom:100},
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right;

  //a simple color scale to correlate to data
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["#646464", "#ffff00"])


 //create svg
var svg = d3.select("#map")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        //here I attmpt to fill the svg with a different color.  but it is unresponsive
      .attr("fill", "blue")
```

As you can see at the end of this code block, I call .attr("fill"... on the SVG element but can't get the color to render.  Maybe this relates to why my cursor is unresponsive in this space.

continuing...

```
  //set projection type to 2D map or 3d globe dependinding on argument passed see function below
var projection = setMapType(mapType, width, height);

      //a function to call on visualize() to set projection type for map style.
function setMapType(mapType, width, height) {
  if(mapType === "mercator") {
    let projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .translate([ width / 2, height / 2 ])
    .scale(180)
    return projection;
  }else if (mapType === "orthographic"){
    let projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
    .clipAngle(90)
    .scale(240);
    return projection;
  }

  //pass path lines to projections
var path = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection);

  //here I create and call the drag function only when globe projection is displayed elected
if(mapType == "orthographic"){
  var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged);
    svg.call(drag);
}


  //coordinate variables
var gpos0, 
    o0;

function dragstarted(){
  gpos0 = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  o0 = projection.rotate();  
}

function dragged(){
  var gpos1 = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  o0 = projection.rotate();

  var o1 = eulerAngles(gpos0, gpos1, o0);
  projection.rotate(o1);

  svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
}

  //load in the topojson file
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "world110m.json")
  .await(ready)
```

The above functions refer to the math functions required to calculate orthographic rotation.  You can see them in the block of code by ivyywang in the first link, at the top.

```
function ready (error, data){
    if (error) throw error;
    //output data to see what is happening
  console.log("topojson data: ")
  console.log(data);

    //I suspect there may be an issue with this code. 
  countries = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.countries)
    //bind dataById data into countries topojson variable
  .features.map(function(d) {
    d.properties = dataById[d.id];
    return d
  });

  console.log("countries:")
  console.log(countries)
```

I suspect the countries variable just above might be the culprit, mostly because I don't entirely understand this code.  In this variable, I am binding my countryStatistics data processed by `keyIdToData()`, as a nested object "properties" with my topojson data.  I console log it to see the data.

```
  svg.selectAll(".country")
    .data(countries)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "country")
    .attr("d", path)

    //make fill gradient depend on data
    .attr("fill", function(countries){
        //if no data, country is grey
      if(countries.properties == undefined){
        return "rgb(100 100 100)";
      }
        //else pass data to colorScale()
      return colorScale(countries.properties.literacy)
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        //on hover set class hovered which simply changes color with a transition time
      d3.select(this).classed("hovered", true)
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("hovered", false)
    })
  }
};
```

finally we have this little function which

```
  //this function build dataById[] setting data keyed to idTopo
function keyIdToData(d){
  countryStatistics.forEach(function(d) {
    dataById[d.idTopo] = d;
  });  
}
```

**Possibilities:** It seems that my SVG render is excluding my empty (non-country) area.  Could be an issue with my SVG construction?  Or possibly I am interfering with the SVG construction when I alter the data and append my dataById into my topojson?

Thanks for making it this far keyboard ninja. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Your mouse interaction is only on the where paths are drawn within a parent `g`, not the space in between. The fill you apply to the `g` is overridden by the styling you apply to the child paths.

---

Looking through what you have, your variable `svg` holds a `g`:

```
//create svg
var svg = d3.select("#map")
  .append("svg")
  ...
  .append("g")  // return a newly created and selected g
  ...
  .attr("fill", "blue") // returns same g
```

For mouse interaction, the `g` can be interacted with only where elements exist within it. For the `g`, the `fill` attribute won't do anything directly, it only is applied to presentation elements (and animations):

> As a presentation attribute, it [fill] can be applied to any element but it
>   has effect only on the following eleven elements: `<altGlyph>`,
>   `<circle>`, `<ellipse>`, `<path>`, `<polygon>`, `<polyline>`, `<rect>`, `<text>`,
>   `<textPath>`, `<tref>`, and `<tspan>` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill))

The use of `fill` on a `g` is instead coloring child elements, your paths. Though you color those directly, so the blue has no visual effect:

```js
var g = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("fill","orange");
  
// Inherit fill:
g.append("rect")
  .attr("width",50)
  .attr("height",50)
  
// Override inheritable fill:
g.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("width",50)
  .attr("height",50)
  .attr("fill","steelblue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**

You need to create an element to interact with for dragging where there is currently no path.

---

Now, I don't think you want to make the entire svg background blue, just the part of the globe that is not part of a country. You can do this with a geojson sphere. Technically not part of the geojson spec, d3 recognizes a geojson of type shere as covering the entire planet (as such it takes no coordinates). Prior to adding the countries to the globe, add a sphere, this gives an element for drag events to interact with:

```
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path({type:"Sphere"})
  .attr("fill","blue");
```

This fills the oceans (and the land), over which we can append the countries. Now as both the sphere and the countries are part of the same `g`, we can implement a drag over the whole earth same as you do now, but now there are no holes where mouse interaction won't work.

Here's a quick demo with an orthographic projection and the most rudimentary of drag functions:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg").append("g");

var projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .translate([250,250])
  
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1/world/110m.json").then( function(data) {

  var world = {type:"Sphere"}
  
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(world)
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill","lightblue");
    
  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(topojson.feature(data,data.objects.land).features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill","lightgreen")
    .attr("d",path);
  
  
  svg.call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", function() {
      var xy = d3.mouse(this);
      projection.rotate(xy)
      svg.selectAll("path")
       .attr("d",path);
    }))
  

 
 
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>

<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: This looks like the answer.  I'm parsing through and applying it.  Will update you with how it goes.

Comment: One Note:  this answer fixes the issue, but originally the blue would only render after firing the drag function.  I resolved this by placing the var = world creation and svg.appending inside my function ready (){}